# Subclipse shows conflict on folder, no way to merge

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using Juno SR2 on Windows, with Subclipse 1.8 (JavaHL 1.7.9), against a svn:// repository. Sometimes during synchronization I would see some folder is marked in red as having conflict, the files under the folder are all checked in without issue, just the folder itself having this problem. I don't want to revert, so I tried "Mark as Merged", but this pops up error " (Access is denied)", I have no idea what this means or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 9):

I often get this problem after ignoring resources in subfolders of the folder in question. Simply updating the folder gets rid of the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that when you make a `svn update` to the folder it resolves the problem.